# "Closure" of a polynomial ring by fraction field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$, $A$ a regular noetherian $k$-algebra, $K$ the fraction field of $A$ and $\bar{K}$ an algebraic closure of $K$. Does there exist a *noetherian* ring $B$ and an injective ring homomorphism, $A \to B$ such that

1) the fration field of $B$ is $\bar{K}$

2) the Krull dimension of $A$ and $B$ are the same.

3) there exists a non-empty dense open subset $U$ of $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ such that the natural morphism $\mathrm{Spec}(B) \to \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ factors through $U$ and is surjective onto $U$.

I have been trying to get some kind of integral closure of $A$ in $\bar{K}$ but have not yet figured out how to do this properly. I think one way is to take finite field extension $L$ of $K$, take the subring of $L$ by adjoining the (finitely many) additional algebraic elements and then take the integral closure. But then I should take some kind of limit to get to $\bar{K}$, which I have not been able to work out.

Is this the right way to approach the problem? Or do we need additional assumptions on $A$ and $K$? Any hint/idea/reference on this question will be most welcome.

Comment: With your assumptions, in particular you must have $\overline{K}$ a finite extension of $K$. Is such a thing possible with $K\neq\overline{K}$?

Comment: @Mohan I have edited the question and removed the criterion of finite type but added a criterion of noetherian ring. Can we have a positive answer now?

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that there's a positive answer in the generality of the question. (Could be wrong.) For $\operatorname{Frac} B$ to be $\overline K$, $B$ needs to have *a lot* of elements algebraic over $A$ but not contained in $A$. It seems to me it will be hard for $B$ to be noetherian and also satisfy $\operatorname{Frac} B = \overline K$.

Comment: Just literally taking the integral closure of $A$ in $\overline K$ should give you (1), (2), and (3) [actually, $\operatorname{Spec} B\rightarrow\operatorname{Spec} A$ would be surjective], but I think it usually won't be noetherian.